# How to run Chrome/Firefox with disabled pdf plugin from watir script?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, automation, watir-webdriver

In the new chrome versions are there any desired capabilities?
For disabling the pdfDocuments in the chrome 59 i was facing this issue

Comment: Look at [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). You can easily set options or profiles under witch u want to run webdriver.

Comment: But I need the capability and its value for disabling pdf